# How can I do a sum of distinct values using minimal code in SAS

Tags: sas

The SAS `proc sql` allows user to do a `count(distinct colname)` , based on some group by dimension(s). What is the fastest way to achieve the same feature for `SUM(distinct colname)`?

```
data: have
grp1 grp2 col1 col2
a     b    20   .
a     b    30   10
a     b    20   10
a     b     .   10
```

data want:

```
grp1 grp2 col1_sum     col2_sum
a      b    50(20+30)   10
```

So basically, for the dimension (a,b), I need a sum of the distinct values in col1 and col2.

Comment: can you clarify a bit more

Comment: Did you try the syntax you posted in your query?  Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

sum(distinct col) as mentioned in your question should work:

```
data have;
input grp1 $1. grp2 $3 col1 col2;
datalines;
a b 20 .
a b 30 10
a b 20 10
a b  . 10
;run;

proc sql;
select
  grp1, grp2,
  sum(distinct col1) as s1,
  sum(distinct col2) as s2,
from have
group by grp1, grp2;
run;
```

... should yield results:

```
grp1 grp2   s1   s2
---- ---- ---- ----
   a    b   50   10
```